# I have no idea what Differential Forms are...

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms

So in my Calc 3 class we use Shifrin's "Multivariable Mathematics", and his discussion on Differential Forms and Integration on Manifolds is impossible for me to follow.

Can someone recommend resources so I can understand this chapter?

Edit: I'm lost in the notation and a lot of the linear algebra, the section "The Multilinear Setup" was very confusing. How can scalars form a basis for Rn? ({dx1,...dxn})

Edit2: (I'm trying here) My question can be condensed to, "Throw resources at me that you found helpful in understanding differential forms that is meant for an undergraduate to be able to follow"

Comment: You can probably ask him yourself... I think he is around this site a bit....

Comment: Is there a way to tag him?

Comment: This question is impossible to follow because you haven't specified anything that confuses you.

Comment: Sorry this whole chapter is a mess for me... I think I just need to understand some material on multilinear algebra before I can tackle this....

Comment: why is this getting downvoted...do y'all want me to apologize for being so stupid a whole chapter goes over my head? geez, just looking for resources...I'm only a first year haven't been studying this all my life like some people here.

Comment: Wonderful: *A Geometric Approach to Differential Forms* (arxiv.org/abs/math/0306194).

Comment: thank you <3 @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla

Comment: I downvoted. The question is too broad and in its present form is unanswerable.

Comment: I appreciate you are trying and this is a difficult topic. Perhaps narrowing it down to the first thing you don't get? Sometimes misconceptions arise from earlier learning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Omar,

This is tough for most students the first time through. Here are two suggestions:

(1) You might look at Steve Weintraub's [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0127425101), which is quite concrete.

(2) You might find my [lectures](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCp9W-et2Zbx7u5_VMiXGtPQ) from the UGA course based on that text helpful, with examples and a bit more interaction with students. (Note that the last ten minutes or so of the original lecture on differential forms got deleted, and so there is a redo of that lecture one year later labeled Day 24 (complete).)

But I do need to respond to the one question you asked. $dx_1,\dots,dx_n$ are *not* scalars. They are linear maps from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$. Namely, $dx_i(\mathbf v) = \mathbf v\cdot\mathbf e_i$, i.e., the $i$th component of $\mathbf v$ when you write it as we did starting page 1 of the course.

By the time you get into computational stuff with line integrals and surface integrals, it will just start to make more sense. Keep on going!

Comment: thank you! this class can get very frustrating at times, and I've found it helpful to try to pull knowledge from as many resources as possible, thanks for the references!